# Animating blocks without eating up memory in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, quartz-2d

I am working on a progress indicator that has a background which is made of several squares drawn on different layers in a UIView. I am trying to animate those squares so they fade in opacity. Think digital squares like when your cable box is on the fritz, but fading in and out.

Is there a better way then using CAAnimations and setting each CALayer opacity like so where

```
innerImage.layer.opacity = randomNum;
```

I am trying to keep from using to much memory.

Comment: well if the thing you are doing is too heavy... you can try to implement "just" this behavior, use an overlay layer... maybe break it into 10 discrete levels and cache the objects... if that doesn't work try it in OpenGL...

Comment: Have you tried this yet and measure the memory it uses? Maybe wait with optimising until there is actually a reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` is an abstraction over Core Animation (which has `CALayer` and `CAAnimation`). So comparing the  `UIView` which belongs to `UIKit` with `CAAnimation` which belongs to `CoreAnimation` is a bit flawed.

[image]

Without looking at the code its tough to say about memory usage. But it should have little or no impact on your app's memory perf unless you are doing some blunders.

`UIKit` and `CoreAnimation` layers are heavily cached. So once a animation is rendered the framework would reuse the cached view to quicken performance. Also all CoreAnimations are run on GPU with its own processor and memory registers. The progress bar should be a breeze for this framework. I have done lot more complex things and the framework hardly broke a sweat. Hope this helps...

Check this immensely useful link - [Designing for iOS Graphics Performance](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/36591648724/designing-for-ios-graphics-performance)